# How to map Product entity so that it is managed by Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to build a module under PS 1.7.6.1.

In design, I have a manyToOne relationship between a Product and a Preorder (many preorders can be associated to one product).

The Preorder object is an ORM entity:

```
//mymodule/src/Entity
class Preorder
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_preorder", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_product", type="integer")
     */
    private $productId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $email;

    setter and getter
}
```

In controller:

```
//src/mymodule/src/Controller


use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType;
use PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use MyModule\Entity\Preoder;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Product;

class PreorderController extends FrameworkBundleAdminController
{
public function createAction(Request $request){

        $preorder = new Preorder();
        $preorderForm = $this->createFormBuilder($preorder)
                ->add('email', EmailType::class)
                ->add('productId', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => Product::class,
                ])
                ->getForm();

        $bookingForm->handleRequest($request);

// validate and persist
}}
```

The problem is that the  form builder doesn't recognize the Product entity. It throws a runtime exception:

> Class "Product" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you
>   forget to map it?

I can't find in the core files an example where such a scenario is handled. Thank you very much in advance for guiding/helping me the resolve this issue.

Comment: can we see the product side of the relation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `product_id` is not an entity so there is 0 chance that The `formbuilder` handle it with the `EntityType::class`. you need to properly define (as explained in the [doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html)) your ManyToOne relation with objects

on the product side :

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    // usual stuff

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $preorders;
}
```

and on the preorder side:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    // usual stuff

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="preorders")
     */
    private $product;
}
```

In your formBuilder, `product` will be an `entity` and recognize by as such by the `EntityType::class`

#### EDIT

If your `product` is a legacy class unmapped by the ORM then you can use the [dataTransformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) to help your formBuilder recognize the legacy entity.

```php
namespace App\DataTransformer;

class ProductToIdTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($product)
    {
        if (null === $product) {
            return '';
        }

        return $product->getId();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($product_id)
    {
        if (!$product_id){
            return;
        } 

        //your db logic to retrieve the product

        if (null === $field){
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf("the product '%s' does not exist!", $product_id));
        }

        return $product;

    }
}
```

Then in your formbuilder you'll use a [`CollectionType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) instead:

```php
$preorderForm = $this->createFormBuilder($preorder)
    ->add('email', EmailType::class)
    ->add('product', CollectionType::class, [
        'class' => Product::class,
        //some logic to adapt the different choices to your needs
    ])
;

$preorderForm
    ->get('product')
    ->addModelTransformer(ProductToIdTransformer::class)
;

$preorderForm = $preorderForm->getForm();
```

Comment: I totally agree with you. The problem in the two code snippets you provided is: they assume Product is an ORM entity, while Product is a simple class in legacy code (https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/Product.php). This class is not yet migrated to a Doctrine entity (in my humble understanding). I can see in migrated code that they manage to instantiate a product object using an Adapter and use it inside controllers, but what about this case?

Comment: srroy, I didn't get it as legacy code. take a look to [data-transformers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) it could make the trick and use a `collectionType` instead

Comment: Thank you for your informative link. It sounds a good idea to use a dataTransformer. I will try and come back for details. Can you please edit your answer?

Comment: I added a way to deal with an unmapped class, be aware that it's a more complicated procedure and you need to implement your own logic to retrieve the choices for the `CollectionType`

Comment: To be honnest towards future readers, I didn't end up using Data Transformers because I discovered that my problem isn't correctly described by my OP. After reading the docs and the edit you gave, I am convinced that OP needs this answer, so I marked it as correct. Thank you very much Pierrick